# Represent a many to many relationship in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, data-modeling

I want to represent a many to many relationship in a relational model and I'm having some doubts.

```
CREATE TABLE TipoDeSeguro
(
    tipoSeguro TEXT NOT NULL,
    tipoDeSeguroID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)
;

CREATE TABLE Cobertura
(
    nome TEXT NOT NULL,
    coberturaID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)
;
```

These are the tables I want to join using a many to many relationShip.

```
CREATE TABLE JoinTipoDeSeguroToCobertura
(
    coberturaID INTEGER,
    tipoDeSeguroID INTEGER
)
;
```

This is my junction table. Are both of these tuples PRIMARY KEYS? Should they both reference to their main class?

Best regards

Answer (score 3):

They should be foreign keys and `not null` if needed.

```
CREATE TABLE JoinTipoDeSeguroToCobertura
(
    coberturaID INTEGER not null,
    tipoDeSeguroID INTEGER not null,

    foreign key(coberturaID) references Cobertura(coberturaID),
    foreign key(tipoDeSeguroID) references TipoDeSeguro(tipoDeSeguroID)
);
```

Comment: and probably coberturaID and tipoDeSeguroID should be NOT NULL, right?

Comment: @Perseverance remember to enable the foreign key constraint using 'pragma foreign_keys = on;' and then try to insert nothing for one of the column of the table and you get 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.

Comment: Actually, it *is* possible to insert NULLs into `JoinTipoDeSeguroToCobertura`, so NOT NULL would still be useful, if needed. And both columns should be part of the primary key.

Comment: @Perseverance yeah, they should. Updated the answer.

Comment: @CL. Updated the answer.